# facebook not reading og:description property correctly?

Tags: facebook, properties

When trying to share to facebook from a weebly page I get an error on what is shown in fb.
checking the debugger I get:
inferred Property   The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

when looking at the blog post I see :

""

any idea of what can be happening?

Page URL - http://www.kevinmckiddonline.com/news-blog/chat-recap-gacrew-call-with-makeup-dept-head-norman-leavitt

thanks in advance
B./

edited to add properties ----

Comment: reentering the link and code information:

Comment: http://www.kevinmckiddonline.com/news-blog/chat-recap-gacrew-call-with-makeup-dept-head-norman-leavitt

<meta property="og:description" content="NORMAN LEAVITT Makeup Dept Head | Grey&#039;s Anatomy Sept 24, 2015 #GAcrewcall ** CLICK HERE TO READ CHAT RECAP ** #GAcrewcall is a short weekly video chat with different Grey&#039;s Anatomy CREW members. It..." />

Comment: post your code in question so we can see it. its too bad in comments.

Answer (score 0):

adding properties (hope this time I can copy)

'meta property="og:description" content="NORMAN LEAVITT Makeup Dept Head | Grey's Anatomy Sept 24, 2015 #GAcrewcall ** CLICK HERE TO READ CHAT RECAP ** #GAcrewcall is a short weekly video chat with different Grey's Anatomy CREW members. It..." /

Answer (score 0):

Betina, I tried to give a look at your code, but your link is broken, it goes to a 404 page...

Anyway, I would say you have a lot of characters that might be forbidden, like "# * " etc... Try using regular chars to see what happens!